# How to hide rows in an Excel form if they are blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

I have a daily report form that I email at the end of every shift. Some sections of the report take up many rows if I'm working one shift versus another.

If I'm working first shift the staff breaks section takes up close to 10 rows. If I'm working third shift it only takes up three rows. I end up with multiple blank rows.

My manager told me to remove those rows when I email the report.

I currently use VBA code to select a range to Copy as Picture, to send in the email without the formatting being obliterated by Outlook.

How can I hide the blank rows before the Copy as Picture takes place so I don't have to search for every blank row and hide them manually?

[image: Form Example]

[image: Form Example Showing Formulas]

Also, would the VBA have trouble if there is invisible code already in the cells?

I tried this code hoping it would only hide rows without data, but it hid the entire selection.

```vb
Sub Hide_Rows()
'
' Hide_Rows Macro
'

'
    Sheet1.Select
    Range("A1:H59").Select

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Selection

        If rng.Value = "" Then
    
            rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        
        End If
    
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: From what I can see in your picture, the blank rows are the ones not having anything in column A:A. Would this assumption be correct, since I cannot see up to H:H column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an empty row should be defined as one not having any value in A:A, you can use this compact way:

```
Sub hideUnhideRowsAtOnce()
   Dim rngHid As Range
   
   Set rngHid = Range("A1:A59").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
   rngHid.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   ' do what you have to do
   '
   Stop 'just to see the result. Press F5 to continue
   rngHid.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

If some values may exist on the other columns, please try using the next way:

```
Sub hideUnhideRows()
   Dim rng As Range, rngHid As Range, i As Long
   
   Set rng = Range("A1:H59")

   For i = 1 To rng.rows.count
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(rng.rows(i)) = _ 
                                     rng.Columns.count Then
            addToRange rngHid, Range("A" & i)
        End If
   Next i
   Debug.Print rngHid.address: Stop
   If Not rngHid Is Nothing Then rngHid.EntireRow.Hidden = True
   
   ' do what you have to do
   '
   Stop 'just to see the result. Press F5 to continue
   
    If Not rngHid Is Nothing Then rngHid.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub

Private Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The picture should have included the H:H column, I'm not sure why it didn't. The first code doesn't seem to affect my empty "Staff Breaks" rows, could that be because there is data in those cells in the form of, ""? Is there some way of designating a specific character that the code would recognize to hide rather than checking if cells are blank? (i.e. "=IF(A!A1<>"",A!A1,"Potato")" instead of now where it pastes "" into the cell?)

Comment: @todayimgonnalearn If there are `nullStrings` inside cells, this **does not mean that the rows are empty**. You should state this aspect... Anyhow, **can you define the algorithm based on what to conclude that the row must be hidden**? Should the row be marked to hiding if it is really empty or has only "" (`nullString`) in its cells? Is the empty string a result of a formula? Is it enough to check only in A:A column? What else should we know in order to prepare a piece of working code?

Comment: @todayimgonnalearn You do not say anything... Please, test the (second) updated code. It now count all blank cells (including null strings) and compare with the total columns in the range. It should work, now. Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Apologies, i've been patrolling at work, I'll test the code and get back to you in 10 minutes or less. Thanks.

Comment: @todayimgonnalearn No problem with me. Let us seeing it working as you need...

Comment: tysm. that second method that you updated perfectly solved my issue!